# Mathematical expressions with Floating points

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hello I'm a sort of newbie in Python 2.What is the simplest way to take input and print the result of a mathematical expression which has decimals? For some reason i keep getting a syntax error.Here's the code im trying to run to calculate the mean:

```
a = input()
b = input()
c = input()

print "MEDIA = %.1f\n"%(((a*2)+(b*3)+(c*5))/(10)))
```

Comment: you have an extra close bracket. also, never use `input()`; use `raw_input()` instead and do a `float` conversion.

Comment: remove a closing bracket at the end of the `print` statement

Comment: Still I get a syntax error.

Comment: Please edit the exact error you're getting into the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe what you have is simply a syntax error.

Your parenthesis aren't balanced.

Try:

```
print "MEDIA = %.1f\n"%(((a*2)+(b*3)+(c*5))/(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
a = float(input())
b = float(input())
c = float(input())
```

Or you could add a `.` to the equation:
    print "MEDIA = %.1f\n"%(((a*2.)+(b*3.)+(c*5.))/(10.)))

By adding a `.` to the numbers, you convert them to a float. I think the option of just reading them in as a float is more straight forward.

EDIT:
Sorry, looking closer at your print statement, you just need to remove the ending `)` so that it becomes: `print "MEDIA = %.1f\n"%(((a*2)+(b*3)+(c*5))/(10))`

Comment: `input` explicitly uses `eval` so if the input is a float already, it will evaluated as such.

Comment: No,it doesn't work.It gives a syntax error.

Comment: Oh you are correct, I didn't catch the extra `)` at the end of your print statement

Comment: where do i use eval?

Comment: The syntax error comes from the number of closing brackets. You don't specifically need float conversion here

Comment: Ahh my bad, it looks like the problem was that one closing bracket,thanks guys :)

Answer (score 0):

If your input is float, float(raw_input()) works. but generally, you can use eval(raw_input()). eval gets a string and converts it to the real value of it.
For example:

```
float_str = "1.2345"
f = eval(float_str)
list_str = "[1,2,3]"
l = eval(list_str)
```

Here, "l" will be a list and "f" will be a float.